# Apache Camel AHC-WS Websocket reconnecting to server when server closes connection unexpectedly

Tags: java, websocket, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I'm using AHC-WS component in Apache Camel to connect to a websocket server using WSS. When the server closes the connection, I got the IOException exception and my errorHandler start redelivery but it seems that the redelivery fails (it only restarted once although I specifies 10 for maximum redeliveries) and the only way to resolve this problem is to restart my camel route manually in order to connect to the websocket server again.

```
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("seda:dead")
        .maximumRedeliveries(10).useExponentialBackOff()
        .log("Route exception"));

    fromF("ahc-wss://some-url&bridgeErrorHandler=true&sendMessageOnError=true")
        .filter(exchange -> exchange.getIn().getBody() != null)
        .process(exchange -> {
            String msg = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody();
            log.info("Message size: " + msg.length());
        })
        .log("test done");
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please provide more details, i.e. logs in debug mode